# Embedding fonts on Android, iOS, and Blackberry - is there a bulletproof solution?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, mobile, css

I've been working on a *mobile web* project testing embedded font support, I've tried the Google font API and EOT so far the results are sporadic.

EOT Results so far:-

- Blackberry: No support at all (9700, Bold)
- Android: 2.1< No support 3.0> Some support, but renders with errors.
- iOS: 4> Works perfectly.

Google font API has similar results.

So, are there any bullet proof solutions or alternatives for embedding fonts on the mobile web? Research has yielded little useful information so far, since most of the work online seems to pertain to Apps.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [font-squirrel's font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) - although I have not tested it with Blackberry yet, it even works in IE7 (maybe IE6?) and generally outputs a pretty solid solution.